# Solr Copyfield on dynamic fields regexp issue

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, solr, spell-checking

I'm trying to copy some dynamic fields for spellchecking. However, the . Below are the relevant fields from schema.xml:

```
<dynamicField name="*_text_fr" stored="false" type="text_fr" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_text_frs" stored="true" type="text_fr" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_text_frms" stored="true" type="text_fr" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
```

It doesn't copy anything with:

```
<copyField source="*_text_fr*" dest="textSpellFr" />
```

However, it works with:

```
<copyField source="*_text_fr" dest="textSpellFr" />
<copyField source="*_text_frs" dest="textSpellFr" />
<copyField source="*_text_frms" dest="textSpellFr" />
```

Why doesn't the first option work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DynamicField and CopyField names are not regular expressions. The `*` wildcard can only be used to indicate prefix or suffix, but not both.